# XSetInputFocus fails

Tags: keyboard, focus, xlib

In my Xlib application, I need to set up the keyboard to focus on a specific component, and I though of doing it with `XSetInputFocus`. For some reason I always get a `BadMatch` error even though my window is visible (and the man pages say that the cause for this error is a window which is not visible/mapped). When I say it's visible, I mean that I can see it on the screen, and I know the list of requests was flushed already.

So, instead of sharing my huge code, I found a smaller demo on the internet and tried to modify it. I took the event handling code in Xlib as presented in the [example](http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/xlib-programming/events.c) of an [Xlib programming tutorial](http://users.actcom.co.il/~choo/lupg/tutorials/xlib-programming/xlib-programming.html#events_example) I found. I tried adding the following line:

```
XSetInputFocus (display, win, RevertToNone, CurrentTime);
```

Just before the line

```
/* perform an events loop */
```

The error I got was:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Serial number of failed request:  12
  Current serial number in output stream:  12
```

This is exactly the same error I got in my own application with exactly the same sequence of events:

1. Create a window with `XCreateSimpleWindow` (that shuold be an `InputOutput` window)
2. Use `XSelectInput` and choose in the mask to also get `KeyPressMask`)
3. Map the window (`XMapWindow`)
4. Request focus using `XSetInputFocus` using either `RevertToNone` or `RevertToParent` (both fail)

I suspect it has to do something with the fact that I need to process the events of the window creation using `XNextEvent`, untill I finish handling the reparenting of the window, but in that case I don't know untill when should I wait (which events should I receive before atempting this?). I am currently doing this before the first call to `XNextEvent` in my program.

Any help would be highly appriciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue just yesterday... It's because the X server processes events asynchroniously; thus you need to wait for the window to be mapped before trying to use XSetInputFocus()...

You should call XIfEvent() to determine this.

An example (written in freepascal):

```
// The filter-function, here you should return true if
//  the event parameter matches the one you want
//  in this case, I match the type to be MapNotify and the window to be the correct one
Function WaitForNotify(aDPY: PDisplay; anEvent: PXEvent; arg: TXPointer): LongBool; cdecl;
Begin
    Result:= (anEvent^._type = MapNotify) and (anEvent^.xmap.window = TWindow(arg));
End;

// XIfEvent cycles through the event cue, and evaluates each event through
//  the function you provide it
XIfEvent(dpy, @event, @WaitForNotify, TXPointer(xWindow));

// Then, once this call returns, you're shure you've got focus and you can safely call
//  XSetInpuFocus()
XSetInputFocus(dpy, XWindow, RevertToNone, CurrentTime);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I said in my question "my window is visible" so I thought that's an indication that the map event was processed. I did however follow your suggestion and tried the XIfEvent. I'm afraid it didn't help with my full code, but this may as well be a bug in it. I'll try it with the example I gave when I can get to it. Thanks for the tip, I'll try it!

Answer (score 1):

For me a simplified solution also worked:
After a call to `XMapWindow()` I just called `XSync()` before performing a `XSetInputFocus()`.

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with this problem once and for all with the code found here:
https://www.ultraengine.com/community/blogs/entry/2690-linux-development-progress/

Have never had a problem since. It's a little scary but since the application has
total control (I think and hope) over any time a window is mapped / unmapped it should be fine.

XInputSetFocus is the only command I have encountered that uses this "rest-of-API-is-asynchronous-but-I-want-what-I-want-right-now" design.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.